# Enhanced FOR loops in C++

Tags: java, c++, for-loop

I am switching from Java to C++ and I was wondering whether C++ contains the enhanced for loops that I used in java, in example:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
for (int item : numbers) {
  System.out.println("Count is: " + item);
}
```

Is this same "shortcut" possible in C++?

Comment: @Beginner: Someone just switching to C++ might not know how C++ versioning works. Why not actually make an answer explaining the difference as it relates to the question?

Comment: @PaulManta Not at all. I agree it could be better to explain everything fully, but that could be also done after OP has said "I do not know, what C++XX means." I just wanted to make an shorter answer.....

Comment: @Paul : There's nothing smug about asking a question just because someone else may not know the answer. The question was perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Is this the equivalent of a foreach in C#?

Comment: so many great examples from this question nice

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In C++11, if your compiler supports it, yes it is. It's called range-based for.

```
std::vector<int> v;

// fill vector

for (const int& i : v) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
```

It works for C style arrays and any type that has functions `begin()` and `end()` that return iterators. Example:

```
class test {
    int* array;
    size_t size;
public:
    test(size_t n) : array(new int[n]), size(n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { array[i] = i; }
    }
    ~test() { delete [] array; }
    int* begin() { return array; }
    int* end() { return array + size; }
};

int main()
{
    test T(10);
    for (auto& i : T) {
        std::cout << i;   // prints 0123456789
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer is better than my full compendium of iterating a sequence. ;)

Comment: You certainly have a point there and I stand corrected and convinced.

Comment: @Merlin I cannot see any hypotheses here. Just facts. And those clearly show that there are a gazillion ways of printing something in different versions of C++, some more or less convenient and every way should be known to a programmer. The one using `accumulate` excluded.

Comment: Its behavior is nearly identical to a Python for loop.

Comment: @pmr - FYI, Occam's razor doesn't just apply to hypotheses but to any situation where you can reduce the complexity of something without losing content.

Comment: @pmr - I was only commenting on the *"I see no hypotheses here"* The required information is at the discretion of everyone else :P

Comment: using C11, you get a warning using "int": for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ ... },      
warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long'), as you declared  "size_t size;"    
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }

Answer (score 77):

C++11 does. They are called range-based fors. Remember that you should qualify the type as a reference or a reference to const.

The workaround for C++03 is [BOOST_FOR_EACH](http://www.boost.org/libs/foreach/) or [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/) in combination with [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). More fancy things are possible with Boost.Lambda. Should you be in the mood to frustrate either yourself or your co-workers I recommend the deprecated binders `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <functional>    

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 10, [&]() {return i++;});

  // range-based for
  // keep it simple
  for(auto a : v)
    std::cout << a << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // lambda
  // i don't like loops
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x) { 
      std::cout << x << " ";
    });
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // hardcore
  // i know my lib
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;


  // boost lambda
  // this is what google came up with
  // using for the placeholder, otherwise this looks weird
  using namespace boost::lambda;
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << _1 << " ");
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // fold
  // i want to be a haskell programmer
  std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ref(std::cout), 
                  [](std::ostream& o, int i) -> std::ostream& { return o << i << " "; });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: // snide comments are hilarious, +1

Comment: +1. I didn't imagine `std::accumulate` could be used in this way. Not that I'm going to use it in my code, but I liked its usage here.

Answer (score 15):

There is no such a possibility in C++03. However new standard (C++11) does have it. See example (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for-loop)):

```
int my_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int &x : my_array) {
    x *= 2;
}
```

Consider also using `std::vector<int>` instead of an ordinary array. This is C++ analogy for C data types, which makes life easier.

Comment: How would it know what is the length of array?

Comment: @lukas The compiler would know. You can compute it by yourself also `int arr_len = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);`

Comment: so in other words I can only use them for "stack" arrays? no pointer to array?

Comment: @lukas Yes. But take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378615/1008481 also, there are other cases you can use it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes and no.

**1. Local array: No, but you can easily find the size**

If you have a local array (`int numbers[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4];`) then you can do `size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int)`.

**2. Pointer to array: Not at all, you have to pass the size around separately**

If you have a pointer to an array (`int* numbers = new int[4];`) then you can't figure out the size unless you keep track of it yourself. (or if it's null terminated in the case of a c string, but then you have to iterate through it which is linear running time...)

Note that I don't believe pointer to array is the proper terminology, really you just have a pointer to the first element of the array but space for multiple values has been allocated. Not sure what this is called. Maybe just a pointer?

**3. STL containers: Yes, and you can do some for loop magic using iterators, or just use indices by getting the size**

If you have a vector (`std::vector<int> v(3, 0);`) then you can iterate through it the following ways:

C++11:

```
auto it = v.begin();
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    UseElement(*it);
}
```

Or apparently (also C++11, thanks jrok):

```
for (const int& i : v) { UseElement(i); }
```

C++ (pre-11):

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    UseElement(*it);
}
```

Or using indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    UseElement(v[i]);
}
```

Furthermore, you can use function pointers or functors with STL containers using std algorithm's for_each (`#include <algorithm>`) like so:

```
void foo(int i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}

{
    std::for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), foo);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In the old standard, C++03 (which is from 2003), the language has no built-in support for that kind of for-loop. There are some artifices you can use with Boost, but imo it's not worth including a whole new library for this small convenience feature.

In the new standard, C++11 (which was released just last summer), this is possible; the syntax looks like this:

```
MyType array[] = { ... }
for (MyType& x : array) {
    ...
}
```

*Note that I'm using `MyType& x`, not `MyType x`. In Java everything is a reference. In C++ references have to be explicit, and you declare them using `&`. If you don't use references, the for-loop will copy each element of the array into `x` (which might be expensive to do).*

However, C++11 is not fully supported by most compilers yet. I think Microsoft's Visual C++ supports this feature, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I guess you meant `MyType array[]` instead of `int MyType[]`.

Answer (score 6):

Others already mentioned that this loop style was added in C++11. However C++11 is even better:

```
for (auto const& item: numbers)
{
  std::cout << "Count is: " << item << '\n';
}
```

That way, if you later change the element type of `numbers` from `int` to `long`, or even to some `bigint` class you wrote yourself, you don't need to change that for loop *at all.*

Answer (score 3):

I find this simple macro very useful. The vast majority of my `for` loops involve iterating over an STL container:

```
#define For(it, container) for( typeof((container).begin()) it = (container).begin(); it != (container).end(); ++it)
```

An example:

```
vector<int> vector_of_ints;
... // initialize it somehow
For(integer, vector_of_ints) {
    cout << *integer << endl;
}
```

There are two things to be aware of with this: First, it's an iterator and hence you must dereference it. And second, the second parameter to the `For` will be evaluated many times. I have played with other approaches, but I keep returning to the simplicity of this.

Comment: Note that the typeof operator is nonstandard C++.