# STL algorithms such as for_each applied to more than one arguments

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write something similar to `mem_fun` and `bind1st` etc. so that STL algorithms such as `for_each` can be applied to more than one arguments? Of course, all except one arguments are given, and the one that has not is going to be filled in by the container elements.

Can anyone please give such an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or its twin [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/bind/bind.html). They are used like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), std::bind(std::plus<int>(), _1, 23 ));
```

Also have a look at as many broken ways to iterate as possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378613/105672

Comment: i see. Is it in the stl of c++11?

Comment: @littleEinstein - `std::bind` is part of C++11. If you can't use that, you can use it from [boost](http://www.boost.org).

Comment: std::bind is also in C++03 and boost::bind is in boost (which you should either have or get).

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas, in my opinion, are much clearer.  pmr's example with a lambda instead of `std::bind`:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), [](int n) { return n + 23 });
```

Lambdas can also handle with ease situations that are quite a bit more difficult with bind and friends, for example:

```
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), [](int n) { return n * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX); });
```

Comment: I've tried to find as many ways of iterating here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378613/105672 strangely enough`std::bind` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can do the same which @pmr has posted in this way as well:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), [](int _1) { return _1 + 23} );
```

Compare this with @pmr's solution.

Notice that `_1` from @pmr solution becomes the parameter of the lambda in my solution. You could (in fact, *should*) use better name, of course; I used `_1` so that you could compare and understand what symbol means what.