# C++11 new way for Iterating through vectors?

Tags: c++, class, for-loop

I have a vector and iterated on it like this:

```
for (int i=0,num_of_roads=roads.size();i<num_of_roads;++i)
{
    roads[i]//...
}
```

But I saw some write:

```
for (Road road:roads)
{
    road//...
}
```

May someone explain what's the difference? and will they give same result

Comment: Here is a description with an explanation to what old style loop this is equivalent: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @WernerHenze I don't want to use auto, is what I wrote above the same in both cases?

Comment: You might want to use `Road &road` (if you need to modify the values stored in `roads`) or `const Road &road` (to avoid making copies).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think "const Road &road" should be: "const Road &road:Road" in your solution right?

Comment: Or just always use `auto&&`, as it will do the right thing every time: `for (auto && road : roads)`. You can explicitly add `const` if you want to enforce that you don't change anything (`auto const &&`)

Comment: @BigSur I left off the `:roads` part for brevity.  `for (const Road &road: roads)`.

Comment: While before I was able to write: roads[i].speed() Now I'm getting error for road.speed()

Comment: Note that this is not useful when you need the index.

Comment: I don't need the index, I need to access its method....

Comment: What error do you get for `road.speed()`?

Comment: No need to use `auto`.  Look at "explanation" on the page I linked. Just do the replacement to see what you get for your range-for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enhanced FOR loops in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378583/enhanced-for-loops-in-c)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In particular, if you are getting an error using `road.speed()`, you should show how `Road::speed()` is declared.

Comment: To add to what @Bob__ asked:   Is `roads` `const` in the function where you call `speed()`? Is `speed() const`?

Comment: If `speed()` is not `const`, then remove the `const` on `road`: `for (Road &road: roads)`

Comment: You can use https://cppinsights.io/ to check what the compiler makes out of your range based for.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is simple loop that's been in C/C++ since beginning. The second one is called as the **[range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)** loop. It can be used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container.

**Syntax :**

```
for(declaration : expression)
```

Every iteration of this `for-range` loop creates a local variable x and initializes it to the next element of vector. The loop will end once it reaches `vector.end()`.

The simple syntax of *range-for* loop is - `for (auto road: roads)`. But do note that this will create copies of the element objects. So you won't be able to modify the elements of origin vector

In you case, if you just want to access the methods without modifying the elements you should use this syntax - `for (const auto& road : roads)`. Firstly, this will prevent making copies of objects and then it will also help prevent any accidental modifications to the elements.

---

**Differences -**

1. The first and obvious difference is you have access to element index in simple for-loops. However, in range-for loops, you won't have access to indexes of element. So, unlike in normal for loops( like `arr[i+1]`, `arr[i-2]`,etc )  you won't be having ability to access elements prior to succeeding current element being accessed.
2. The range-for are probably better when you want to iterate over whole vector for reading purposes. range-for loops are optimized that way. They computes the finishing condition only once. Range-for only de-references the iterator once to check for end condition. So, the **standard guarantees that the best possible performance** is achieved when you want to iterate over entire vector, especially for reading purposes.
3. In normal for-loops, you will access the element itself by their index, but if you choose to use range-for loops as - `for(auto elem:vec)`, then this creates copy of each element of vector. This may be costly if the elements of vectors are complex objects. We can prevent this by using `for(auto& elem:vec)` as already mentioned above.

You should use **range-for** loops whenever you just want to iterate over vector without need for index. It will especially be useful when you only want to read the vector element values and the vector consists of complex data-type. You can use const reference when you only want to read the vector. You can use non-const reference in case where you want to modify the objects as `for(auto& elem:vec)` . (Ideally, its better to use references for performance reasons)

This will help in readability as well as help you keep you code simple. Also, you won't see any performance hit as well (rather, slight gains in few cases) and so we don't need to worry about it either.

You can read more about it [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm).

Answer (score -1):

This is called a range-based for loop. It has been discussed here:
[Enhanced FOR loops in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378583/enhanced-for-loops-in-c)

The difference is that in the second one, `road == the value of roads[i]`.
You won't be able to do `road = new Road()` but you can do `roads[i] = new Road()`
Basically can't modify the roads vector